# How to add and overwrite properties from one object to another?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I have a simple utility function:

```
public static function extend(objA:Object, objB:Object):Object {
    objA = objA || {};
    for(var prop:String in objB) {
        if(typeof(objB[prop]) === "object") {
            objA[prop] = extend(objA[prop], objB[prop]);
        } else {
            objA[prop] = objB[prop];
        }
    }

    return objA;
}
```

I currently use it like this:

```
object1 = {prop1: "asd", prop2: {subProp1: 120, subProp2: 360}};
object2 = {prop1: "asd", prop2: {subProp1: 120, subProp2: 5, subProp3: 6}};
object1 = extend(object1, object2);
//object1 now looks like (subProp2 overwritten, subProp3 added):
//{prop1: "asd", prop2: {subProp1: 120, subProp2: 5, subProp3: 6}};
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
object1 = {prop1: "asd", prop2: {subProp1: 120, subProp2: 360}};
object2 = {prop1: "asd", prop2: {subProp1: 120, subProp2: 5, subProp3: 6}};
object1.extend(object2);
```

A lot of resources say that prototyping isn't a good idea with AS anymore. So what's the best way to achieve that in AS3?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would be helpful for you:
http://tobyho.com/2009/05/02/modifying-core-types-in/

But I recommend you avoid that code style in AS3. This is your code:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function(objB:Object):Object {
            var objA:Object = this || {};
            for(var prop:String in objB) {
                if(typeof(objB[prop]) === "object") {
                    objA[prop].extend(objB[prop]);
                } else {
                    objA[prop] = objB[prop];
                }
            }

            return objA;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with prototypes is that they are adding behaviour to existing "classes".

**Why is that bad?**

1. Nobody knows what parts of the code add functionality to the `Object`
   class. It's horrible to read the code because at some point there's
   a method call on Object that's totally new to you.
2. It is prone to naming conflicts. If I want to define a method
   `extend` on `Object`, it'd collide with yours.

There is no clear answer to your question, because your example is too generic. In general, you do not want to add this functionality to all objects, because not all objects need it. And you only want to add/overwrite certain properties.